# display axis description for asp.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

how can I display a small description text for X & Y axis of ASP.NET column chart? I use VS2010/C#

for instance I want to right "Time" for description of X-axis and "Value" for description of Y-axis

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Name";
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Employee Id";
```

[image: Chart X and Y axis names]